# Timers Are Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, timer

I have just done a new layout for my site, and it turns out some of the timers that are supposed to count down aren't counting down.
I was just wondering if anyone could see why it's doing this.
I won't post the snippet on here, but I will post a full pastebin of the code.
Thank you in advance.
Here is the paste: http://pastebin.com/Jxv2eFDR
From line 688 onwards is where we're looking and here is the timer script
Which is near the bottom of the above stated code. I have tried putting the script towards the top before line 688.
http://pastebin.com/ym4xGNJk

Comment: that's a lot of code to ask people to look through - especially as you give no indication of the offending lines of code

Comment: Thread has been updated

Comment: rather than posting the links, post the pieces of code that are not working. I can't tell what the code is doing or where it is failing so I guess others that may have looked at this might also fail to see the wood for the trees. Is it PHP or javascript timers that are failing? Are there any errors? Are there any symptoms other than "not working"?

Comment: They are Java, and no, I used the same as my old code and they work perfectly fine, but not in this.

Comment: I will put on error reporting but all ill get is the deprecated errors I reckon

Comment: And JavaScript I'm quite sure

Comment: Errors I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: global_win in /home/reunite2/public_html/includes/index2.php on line 505

Notice: Undefined index: faction_win in /home/reunite2/public_html/includes/index2.php on line 518

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103286/discussion-between-ramraider-and-brady-magrath).

Answer (score 0):

The errors appear to refer to two particular session variables - undefined index means they are not set. The javascript code relies upon the logic tests:

`if($_SESSION['global_win']){/* run javascript */}` and `if($_SESSION['faction_win']){/* more javascript */}` ~ fix the issue of undefined index or use a conditional test for each of these.

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['global_win'], $_SESSION['faction_win'] ) ){/* proceed with javascript*/ }`
```